# Url causes a forbidden link

Tags: http, url, path, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC5 and when I use Path.Combine to create a link to an MP3 file I get a 403 (forbidden).

Here's how I create the link

```
<a href="@Path.Combine(SiteConfiguration.ContentPath, SiteConfiguration.AlbumsPath, Model.AlbumName, song.Name)" >@song.Name</a>
```

Here are the values of the variables

```
<add key="ContentPath" value="..\Content\Files\" />
<add key="AlbumsPath" value="Mixtapes\" />
```

`Model.AlbumName` and `song.Name` have spaces in them and the Files folder is included as part of the project in the `Content` folder.

The link generated looks like this (although it does get url encoded)

```
http://localhost:49563/..\Content\Files\Mixtapes\Album Name\Song Name.mp3
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: This may be simple, but are you sure those files actually have the correct permissions to be retrieved in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this will be to use the built in application root path providers in .NET.  I am sure you have seen something like this:

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/image.jpg")
```

Where the `~` instructs the parser to go find the root of the application (whether a virtual directory or not) and return that path.  Let's use that in combination of the `Url.Content()` helper to get a path that will always resolve no matter where in your application you use it (meaning, nesting depth).

First, update your app settings (use the ~, fix your slashes)

```
<add key="ContentPath" value="~/Content/Files" />
<add key="AlbumsPath" value="Mixtapes" />
```

Next, update your `<a>` tag with the following

```
<a href="@Path.Combine(Url.Content(SiteConfiguration.AppSettings["ContentPath"]), 
SiteConfiguration.AppSettings["AlbumsPath"], Model.AlbumName, song.Name)" >@song.Name</a>
```

Notice we are using the `Url.Content` in the first part of the `Path.Combine`.  What this will buy you is that you can use this format any place in your application, the framework will parse the `~` and give you the appropriate root link.  You only need to do this for `ContentPath` variable as it is giving you the root of the directory you are looking for.  A tiny bit more typing, a much better result (from my test project below)

```
http://localhost:60306/Content/Files/Mixtapes/Test/Song%20Title
```

Last thought, if you are using these values enough that you factored part of them out to the AppSettings, perhaps you should create your own Url helper that takes two parameters and returns the correct Url.  So that instead of the above, you could simply use

```
<a href="@Url.GenerateSongLink(Model.AlbumName, song.Name)">song.Title</a>
```